# R remove duplicate elements in character vector, not duplicate rows

Tags: r, duplicates

I am hitting a brick wall with this problem.

I have a data frame (dates) with some document ids and dates stored in a character vector:

```
  Doc     Dates
1 12345 c("06/01/2000","08/09/2002")
2 23456 c("07/01/2000", 09/08/2003", "07/01/2000")
3 34567 c("09/06/2004", "09/06/2004", "12/30/2006")
4 45678 c("06/01/2000","08/09/2002")
```

I am trying to remove the duplicate elements in the Dates to get this result:

```
  Doc     Dates
1 12345 c("06/01/2000","08/09/2002")
2 23456 c("07/01/2000", 09/08/2003")
3 34567 c("09/06/2004", "12/30/2006")
4 45678 c("06/01/2000","08/09/2002")
```

I have tried:

```
R>unique(dates$dates)
```

but it removes duplicate rows by Dates:

```
  Doc     Dates
1 12345 c("06/01/2000","08/09/2002")
2 23456 c("07/01/2000", 09/08/2003")
3 34567 c("09/06/2004", "12/30/2006")
```

Any help on how to remove only the duplicate elements in Dates, and not remove duplicate Rows by Dates?

**** Updated with data

```
# Match some text string (dates) from some text:

df1$dates <- as.character(strapply(df1[[2]], "((\\D\\d{1,2}(/|-)\\d{1,2}(/|-)\\d{2,4})|    ([^/]\\d{1,2}(/|-)\\d{2,4})|((JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV){1}[\\s|-]{0,2}\\d{1,4}(\\D[\\s|-]{0,}\\d{2,4}){0,}))"))

# Drop first 2 columns from dataframe
df2<-df1[ -c(1,2)]

# List data
>df2
872                     7/23/2007
873 c(" 11/4/2007", " 11/4/2007")
874   c(" 4/2/2008", " 8/2/2007")
880                    11/14/2006

> class(df2)
[1] "data.frame"

> class(df2$dates)
[1] "character"

> dput(df2)
structure(list(dates = c("NULL", "NULL", " 7/23/2007", "c(\" 11/4/2007\", \" 11/4/2007\")", 
"c(\" 4/2/2008\", \" 8/2/2007\")", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", 
"NULL", " 11/14/2006")), .Names = "dates", class = "data.frame", row.names = 870:880)
```

So my issue is how to get rid of the duplicate dates in Row 873?

Comment: please provide the output from `dput(dates)`. It'd help to just copy/paste instead of recreating your data.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
within(dates, Dates <- lapply(Dates, unique))
```

Comment: Arun - can't copy/past from the system I'm using (makes asking ? very difficult).  I will try the within, and barring any success will create a dataset I can use outside the system and repost.  Thanks.

Comment: FYI - I solved the issue:  wrap a lapply(strapply(), unique) around the strapply:  df1$date <- as.character(lapply((strapply(df1[[2]], "((\\D\\d{1,2}(/|-)\\d{1,2}(/|-)\\d{2,4})|([^/]\\d{1,2}(/|-)\\d{2,4})|
((JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV){1}[\\s|-]{0,2}\\d{1,4}(\\D[\\s|-]{0,}\\d{2,4}){0,}))")),unique))

Comment: @user2547308, I suggest you post that as an answer, for completeness and better formatting. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue I was having of removing duplicate values from a character vector - wrap a lapply(strapply(), unique):

```
df1$date <- as.character(lapply((strapply(df1[[2]], "((\\D\\d{1,2}(/|-)\\d{1,2}(/|-    )\\d{2,4})|(\\s\\d{1,2}(/|-)\\d{2,4})|((JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV){1}[\\s|-]{0,2}\\d{1,4}(\\D[\\s|-]{0,}\\d{2,4}){0,}))")),unique))
```

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

I would `gsub` out `c(` and `)` in dates and then for each row I would call `unique` on a `strsplit` of it using the `,`

UNTESTED but maybe something like:
    `sapply(dates$dates, function(x){
    new.x=gsub("c(|)","",x)
    new.x=strsplit(new.x, ",")
    unique(new.x)
    })`

Comment: I think the column `Dates` is actually a `list`, not string.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for something like this.

```
 df

     Doc                                       Dates
 1 12345                c("06/01/2000","08/09/2002")
 2 23456 c("07/01/2000", "09/08/2003", "07/01/2000")
 3 34567 c("09/06/2004", "09/06/2004", "12/30/2006")
 4 45678                c("06/01/2000","08/09/2002")

 Eval and Parse
 x <- t(sapply(df[,"Dates"],function(x){unique(eval(parse(text = x)))}))
 df$Dates <- paste(x[,1],x[,2],sep=",")

 df
      Doc                 Dates
  1 12345 06/01/2000,08/09/2002
  2 23456 07/01/2000,09/08/2003
  3 34567 09/06/2004,12/30/2006
  4 45678 06/01/2000,08/09/2002


 Same can be achieved using Regex:

 paste(unique(unlist(strsplit(gsub("c\\(|\\)","",'c("24/07/2012","22/01/2012","24/07/2012")'),","))),sep = "")

 [1] "\"24/07/2012\"" "\"22/01/2012\""

 Haven't tried on data but works
```