# In-row duplicates and replace values in df with corresponding values

Tags: r

I have a data frame looking somehow like this

```
> df
          x  y  z
    [1,] NA  6 11
    [2,]  1  7 12
    [3,]  2  8 13
    [4,]  3  9 14
    [5,]  4 10 15
    [6,]  5 NA NA
```

And a character vector looking somehow like this

```
> a
 [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j" "k" "g" "m" "n" "o"
```

What I want to achieve is two tasks. (1.) to replace the numbers in df with the corresponding character values in a. (2.) to find duplicates row-wise instead of column-wise. The NAs are allowed to stay for now.

Here is the example data:

```
x<-c(NA,1:5)
y<-c(6:10,NA)
z<-c(11:15,NA)
df<-cbind(x,y,z)
a<-c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","g","m","n","o")
```

A rather humble and very slow solution for (1.) is:

```
new<-data.frame()
for(i in 1:ncol(df)){
  for(j in 1:nrow(df)){
    new[j,i] <- as.character(a[df[j,i]])
  }
}
```

It works but takes forever on my 1mil * 64 dataset. And it seems there is a solution for (2.) [already here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17452584/r-remove-duplicate-elements-in-character-vector-not-duplicate-rows) but I do not know how to apply it on my problem. The final result should look like this then:

```
> new
    V1   V2   V3
1 <NA>    f    k
2    a    g    g
3    b    h    m
4    c    i    n
5    d    j    o
6    e <NA> <NA>
```

But the second g in row 2 needs to be replaced by NA. I hope it is clear what I would like to do and somebody has a solution for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can just use

```
r1 <- `dim<-`(a[df], dim(df))
```

If we need to replace the duplicates with NA

```
t(apply(r1, 1, function(x) replace(x, duplicated(x), NA)))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is amazing and works like a charm. Super fast as well